# Насколько безопасно использовать постоянное соединение с PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

Пишу web-приложение на python. Использую асинхронный PostgreSQL - `asyncpg`.

Приложение и база данных находятся на одном сервере. Вопрос: насколько безопасно использовать постоянное соединения с БД? Может ли оно отвалится каким-то образом? Может ли PostgreSQL закрыть его по какой-либо причине? Просто если соединение отваливается, то всё приложение перестаёт работать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвалиться может, СУБД закрыть его может, но держать соединение всё равно стоит. Если вы используете [пул соединений](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/usage.html#connection-pools), то библиотека сама позаботится о доступности соединения.

Comment: Спасибо, в документации пример с aiohttp, я использую fastapi, попытаюсь адаптировать это под мою ситуацию =)

Answer (score 0):

Для увеличения безопасности коннект к базе можно осуществлять через localhost:port или вообще, через socket